# How to make confirm password by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna change validate email to confirm password, how to make it (code) properly ?
I really don't know about jQuery anyway. Thanks in advance.

```
$("#send").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var contact = $("#contactno").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
var paswword = $("#password").val();
var confirmpassword=$("#confirmpasword").val();
    if (name == "" || email == "" || contactno == "" || message == "")
    {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    }
    else
    {
        if (validateEmail(email)) {
            $("#contactdiv").css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
        }
        function validateEmail(email) {
            var filter = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;

            if (filter.test(email)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can set an `if` case for `if(password == confirmpassword)`?

Comment: Don't put your function declarations inside you click handler... Horrible

Comment: There isn't a need for the function `validateEmail()` as it is only called from a single location and only available within that specific function.  It's bascially superfluous.

Comment: Actually That was contact form but I wanna transform it to register form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your variable declaration, it should be `password` instead of `paswword`. This is how you can check that they match:

```
if (password != confirmpassword) {
    //passwords dont match
} else {
    //passwords do match 
}
```

Comment: I've changed it, but send button can't clicked.

Comment: Add your HTML to your question

Comment: Actually That was contact form but I wanna transform it to register form.